# How to add elements within an array the most efficient way?

Tags: python, arrays, function, dot-product

I have an array

```
myarray = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]
```

and I want to get

```
myarray_2 = [a + c + e, b + d + f]
```

How can I do this without loops? What would be the most efficient way or maybe, the most pythonic approach?

Comment: it's not clear what are the actual values?

Comment: What have you tried so far that you think is inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one line approach could be to transpose the matrix and sum the rows:

```
list(map(sum, zip(*myarray)))
```

The idiom `zip(*myarray)` transposes the input by creating an iterator over tuples containing the corresponding elements from each row.

If you are dealing with numerical data, using numpy might be a better approach:

```
np.array(myarray).sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`, `sum`, and a list-comprehension:

```
myarray = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

myarray_2 = [sum(t) for t in zip(*myarray)]

print(myarray_2)
```

Output:

```
[9, 12]
```

This will work no matter the size of the sublists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
myarray_2 = list(map(sum, zip(*myarray)))
```

For example, if `myarray = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`, `myarray_2` would be `[9, 12]`